# Detecting a full byte[] buffer?

Tags: java, arrays, java-me, buffer

As we all know java allows us to use byte array as a buffer for data. My case here is with J2me

The scenario here is that I have two buffers of equal size and I need to swap them as they get full one by one ..

In detail
Two buffers buff1 and buff2

Reading data from Buff1 while writing other data to buff2

Then when buff2 gets full

They swap their position now reading from buff2  and writing to buff1

The above cycle goes on

So how do I detect when a buffer is full and is ready to be swapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so how do I detect when a buffer is full

The buffer itself is never full (or empty). It is just a fixed amount of reserved memory.

You need to keep track of the useful parts (i.e. those with meaningful data) yourself. Usually, this is just an integer that counts how much bytes were written into the buffer (starting from the beginning).

When that integer reaches the buffer length, your buffer is "full".

Comment: Oh yes ! Holy S**t ..that's so simple.. Hehe I need to learn the basics again..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Three values can be used to specify the state of a buffer at any given moment in time: [SOURCE LINK](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-nio/section5.html)

```
* position
* limit
* capacity
```

**Position**

When you read from a channel, you put the data that you read into an underlying array. The  position  variable keeps track of how much data you have written. More precisely, it specifies into which array element the next byte will go. Thus, if you've read three bytes from a channel into a buffer, that buffer's  position will be set to 3, referring to the fourth element of the array.

**Limit**

The limit variable specifies how much data there is left to get (in the case of writing from a buffer into a channel), or how much room there is left to put data into (in the case of reading from a channel into a buffer).
The position is always less than, or equal to, the limit.

**Capacity**

The capacity of a buffer specifies the maximum amount of data that can be stored therein. In effect, it specifies the size of the underlying array -- or, at least, the amount of the underlying array that we are permitted to use.
The limit can never be larger than the capacity.

```
so how do I detect when a buffer is full and is ready to be swapped?
```

Check the values of the position and the capacity fields or the limit .